# How to change display scaling settings in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, display, screen, scaling, lxqt

How to change display scaling settings in `Lubuntu`, so that the font, the icons and the buttons are bigger, similar to `Mac OS X`, in size?

[image]

Comment: Scaling is a known issue with LXQt - https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-config/issues/401  @Andy's answer would require adding a fair amount of KDE (inc. KF5/KDE Frameworks) to your system, where LXQt (L=*light*) aims to be a *light*, and thus doesn't include it.

Answer (score 10):

In Lubuntu 21.10, I had to go through the following steps:

1. Open *LXQt Configuration Center -> Session Settings -> Environment Variables (Advanced)* or run `lxqt-config-session`
2. Add `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` with value `2`
3. Add `GDK_DPI_SCALE` with value `2`
4. Add `XCURSOR_SIZE` with value `64`

[image: Screenshot of LXQt Session Settings showing the three additional environment variables]

5. Open *LXQt Configuration Center -> Appearance -> Font* and set *Resolution (DPI)* to `192`

[image]

- Discussion: https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/discussions/2054
- Feature request: https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/2173

Comment: I can confirm that "this is the way". In my case, I have a stretch virtual display (for remote operation via smartphone) and played with scale values: decimals are allowed, GDK and QT doesn't have to be equals, for what is worth.

Comment: Does this work for a laptop which has a HiDPI screen and then plugging in an external monitor that is _not_ HiDPI? Meaning, is this scaling global, or per-display?

Comment: your screen shots are drop dead...